# Difference between group id, Client id and id in KafkaListener Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am starting to work with Spring Boot 2 and Spring Kafka, I don't quite understand what's the difference between `group id`, `Client id`, and `id in` in `KafkaListener` interface.
I know group ID is used by Kafka broker to manage multiple Consumer in the same group, but what about the others? what advantage do I get by setting them?  where can I see the effect of setting or not setting them?

Based on their java doc :

```
/**
     * The unique identifier of the container managing for this endpoint.
     * <p>If none is specified an auto-generated one is provided.
     * @return the {@code id} for the container managing for this endpoint.
     * @see org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry#getListenerContainer(String)
     */
String id() default "";

/**
 * Override the {@code group.id} property for the consumer factory with this value
 * for this listener only.
 * @return the group id.
 * @since 1.3
 */
String groupId() default "";

/**
 * When provided, overrides the client id property in the consumer factory
 * configuration. A suffix ('-n') is added for each container instance to ensure
 * uniqueness when concurrency is used.
 * @return the client id prefix.
 * @since 2.1.1
 */
String clientIdPrefix() default "";
```

Answer (score 12):

Your `groupId` understanding is correct.

The `id` is like a bean name in Spring Framework. However this one is used in the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` boundaries only. So, if you need a lifecycle control over the particular `KafkaListenerContainer` created for the mentioned `@KafkaListener`, you need to inject `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` and use the mentioned `getListenerContainer()` for the appropriate `id`.

The `clientIdPrefix` is reflection of exact `client.id` property of the [Kafka Consumer](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs):

> An id string to pass to the server when making requests. The purpose of this is to be able to track the source of requests beyond just ip/port by allowing a logical application name to be included in server-side request logging.

Comment: what are they gonna do in case of scaling my Kafka consumer horizontally? do they provide any help in case of tracking or debugging if I set them (id and client id)? I still don't' understand the point of setting them

Comment: The `id` is something internal for the Spring Application Context. This should not be unique globally. The `groupId` is indeed good option for scaling when you would like to have several competing consumers on the same topic. The `clientIdPrefix` is really useful to determine via monitoring system what and where is consuming. That's like a global identificator for your application.

Comment: Please be carefull that if you specify the `id` property it will override the group id.

Doc says:
Note: When provided, this value will override the group id property in the consumer factory configuration, unless idIsGroup() is set to false or groupId() is provided.

Comment: @Ena if  you specify `groupId`, then groupId() will provide data, so it is not true.